# Webscraping hidden product names from source code

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to webscrape the product names from https://maanesten.com/product-category/accessories-2/hair-claws/. Turns out the source code only provided a list of 20 products unlike the dynamic view seen on their website and through inspect on chrome. Meaning the rest of the details are burried somewhere. How should I go about doing this?

Here is my current code:

```
DRIVER_PATH = 'pathto/chromedriver'
options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1200")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
driver.get("https://maanesten.com/product-category/accessories-2/hair-claws/")

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
elements = WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='content']")))
for element in elements: 
    print(element.text)

driver.quit()
```

As expected, it only returned 20 products up till this part of the source code where ul ends and it becomes the start of a pagination that is not visible:

```
<li class="last original-cat-id-loop-346 original-prod-id-loop- post-118264 product type-product status-publish has-post-thumbnail product_cat-aw20 product_cat-hair-claws taxable shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple product-cat-aw20 product-cat-hair-claws outofstock">
    
    <a href="https://maanesten.com/product/helo-hairclaw-peach-sky/">   
    <a href="https://maanesten.com/product/helo-hairclaw-peach-sky/">
        
        <img src="/wp-content/themes/maanesten/images_optimized/126044-shop_catalog-product_page.jpg"><p class="wc-new-badge"><span>New</span></p><h3>Helo Hairclaw Peach Sky</h3>  
    </a>
    
    </a>
</li>

    
    
    
    </ul>

    <nav class="woocommerce-pagination">
    <ul class='page-numbers'>
    <li><span class='page-numbers current'>1</span></li>
    <li><a class='page-numbers' href='https://maanesten.com/product-category/accessories-2/hair-claws/page/2/'>2</a></li>
    <li><a class='page-numbers' href='https://maanesten.com/product-category/accessories-2/hair-claws/page/3/'>3</a></li>
    <li><a class='page-numbers' href='https://maanesten.com/product-category/accessories-2/hair-claws/page/4/'>4</a></li>
    <li><span class="page-numbers dots">&hellip;</span></li>
    <li><a class='page-numbers' href='https://maanesten.com/product-category/accessories-2/hair-claws/page/8/'>8</a></li>
    <li><a class='page-numbers' href='https://maanesten.com/product-category/accessories-2/hair-claws/page/9/'>9</a></li>
    <li><a class='page-numbers' href='https://maanesten.com/product-category/accessories-2/hair-claws/page/10/'>10</a></li>
    <li><a class="next page-numbers" href="https://maanesten.com/product-category/accessories-2/hair-claws/page/2/">&rarr;</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>


</div>
```

How do I go about accessing the rest of the products through selenium on python? Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the page loads the first 20 products. Then there's some JS code that fetches more products as you scroll, meaning it's dynamically fetching the rest of the products. I was able to figure out the XHR calls that's fetching the products dynamically.

[image]

You would have to emulate these XHR calls to get the rest of the products

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I have limited knowledge on what XHR is, but I just read up that I can technically just do the same .get method, would I be right to say that I would just need a loop to go through the pages and extract each product name each time ? or is there a more legitimate way of emulating these XHR calls?

Comment: Going through the XHR response and request `https://maanesten.com/product-category/accessories-2/hair-claws/.....` it looks like there are 6 requests made to the same endpoint but with different parameters (look at the last part of the XHR, it says page=2, page=3, etc). The response for each of these is HTML.
So yeah, the easiest way to get the products would be to loop through these 6 URLs and parse the response

Comment: awesome! thanks alot for your help, I was pulling my hair for hours and now I learnt something new!